# "0" as first number in html input number element

Tags: html, forms, input

I have an input element like follows:

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="99">
```

By default, the field must be empty. When clicking on the "arrow-up" button generated by the browser, then `1` appears as first number. However, I need `0` as first number. This is also what I would expect. In fact, setting `min="0"` and `min="1"` makes no difference in this regard. Both start with `1`. Is there a way to achieve this without creating my own control element with JavaScript?

Comment: _"without creating my own control element with JavaScript?"_ - you could _enhance_ the behavior of the existing field with JS, perhaps ...? https://jsfiddle.net/49yL1bxp/ - keeping track of the previous value (whenever the field gets focus), and then _setting_ the value to `0`, if it got changed into `1`, an the previous value was still and empty string ... Only in that example, it will also set it to `0` again, if you put the cursor into the field and _type_ a `1` into it - so it would need additional checks for keydown/keypress or something like that.

Comment: +1 for this Intersting question, I couldn't find a way to do it without JS, I'm not even sure if it's possible.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. My question was maybe not sufficiently clear. What I meant is whether this is possible without JavaScript at all. If JavaScript is required, then the `input` event you mentioned is far better than the `change` event, because it will trigger before the user input is shown in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `oninput` event to initialize it and set its first value to 0. But you will also need a keypress event so if you type a value into it by hand, then it will not change that to 0.

```js
function initialize(item) {
    if (!item.getAttribute("initialized")) {
        item.setAttribute("initialized", true);
        if (item.value == 1) item.value = 0;
    }
    if (item.value === "") {
        item.removeAttribute("initialized");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="99" oninput="initialize(this);" onkeypress="this.setAttribute('initialized', true);" onpaste="this.setAttribute('initialized', true);">
```

You can work with classes instead:

```js
function initialize(item) {
    if (!item.classList.contains("initialized")) {
        item.classList.add("initialized");
        if (item.value == 1) item.value = 0;
    }
    if (item.value === "") {
        item.classList.remove("initialized");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="99" oninput="initialize(this);" onkeypress="this.setAttribute('initialized', true);" onpaste="this.setAttribute('initialized', true);">
```

Comment: There is an issue, if the user holds the up arrow (e.g. to set a big value without moving hands to keyboard), your script sets zero after the user stops holding.

Comment: @SNBS it did not reproduce for me.

Comment: Thank you. I also can not reproduce the issue raised by @SNBS. However, there are still several issues. 1) when pasting a value with the mouse then it changes the value to `0`. 2) When writing something into the field, then clearing it, then using the arrow buttons, it starts with `1` again. 3) when using `change` then the `1` shows shortly, before being changed to the `0`. Maybe it is better to use the `input` event as suggested above.

Comment: @Rolch2015 thanks for testing and explaining the problems you found. I have made adjustments to the answer and now the problems you have mentioned are no longer reproducing. Can you test and see whether there are still problems? Thanks!

Comment: I added an onpaste event, now it is working (previously, pasting `1` with the mouse still changed it to `0`). Preferably, I would use a data-attribute or refactor it into a class, but this is a good working example to start with. Thank you!

Comment: @Rolch2015 added a quick refactoring for the class-based scenario. I made some quick tests, please let me know if you find any problems with this new approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value to 0

```
<input type="number" min="-1" max="99" value="0">
```

Comment: Initially, the field must be empty, as mentioned in my question. If setting `value="0"`, then this is not the case.

Comment: ooh yeah sorry about that, what happens when you set `min="-1" ` and  `max="99"` ?

Comment: Then it also starts with `1`, I tried it. Furthermore, this would make it possible to set `-1` as value, which would be an invalid value in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an answer! With a bit of javascript you can do that!

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="99" />

<script>
  let inp = document.querySelector("input");

  let done = false;
  inp.addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
    if (!done) {
      done = true;
      ev.target.value = 0;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Same issue as in @LajosArpad 's answer — if the user holds the up arrow (e.g. to set a big value without moving hands to keyboard), your script sets zero after the user stops holding.

Comment: Alright, maybe just change the condition, like: ```js if(!done && ev.target === 0)```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="99" id="input" oninput="if (document.getElementById('input').value === '') document.getElementById('input').value = '0'">
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without any JavaScript, then the right answer would be *no*, because **if you don't specify the default value for a number input, it will be considered 0, even if there's no 0 shown.** You can check this by calling `stepUp` and `stepDown` consequently, which won't change the value. 0 will be shown up. (Your own experience says the same — 1 appears after clicking up arrow, thus the initial value was 1 - 1 = 0.)

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input[type=number]");
input.stepUp();
input.stepDown();
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="99">
```

Hence, if you click the up arrow on a number input without value, 0 will be increased to 1.

The right way to overcome this would be *explicitly* specifying 0 as the default value. It won't confuse users (if you want zero — here's zero for you, and you don't have to increase it) and won't rely on browser assumptions like this one.

However, please note that setting an explicit default value will raise issues with validation: you don't know if the user really wanted 0 or he just forgot about that field (if there's no default value, and the validation system is set up properly, forgetting about the field will raise a validation error). So you have to choose, either have a bad validation system or use JS from other answers here. The second option seems much better for me.

Comment: Since this behavior can be replicated in multiple browsers (and is counter-intuitive in my opinion), is it anywhere described in the specifications? I could not find anything germane to this issue.

Comment: Furthermore, in my case, an empty field represents an empty value (=null in the backend), which is why I can not use 0 as default value. Also, if clearing the field and using the arrow buttons, then it starts with `1` again.

Comment: I think it's not described in any specs, since there is no mention about that even in [the official W3C spec for number inputs](https://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements/input/number). Weird but that's true as you can see.

Comment: Yes, I also looked the W3C specification up. But somewhere there must be something I guess.

Comment: Well maybe there are some browser-specific documents about that. I'm not sure though. I couldn't find anything as well.